# PUN Networking error - No Suitable Method found to override

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm fairly new to C# and unity, and i've been trying to set up the Photon Networking service. I've run into an issue i can't figure out the cause of. Here are the two error messages.

> Assets\PhotonUnityNetworking\Resources\TestConnect.cs(21,41): error CS0246: The Type or namespace name 'DisconnectCause' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Asseta\PhotonUnityNetworking\Resources\TestConnect.cs(21,26): error CS0115 'TestConnect.OnDisconnected(DisconnectCause)': no suitable method found to override.

However, in visual studio, nothing shows up as incorrect.

[image: visual studio screenshot]

Any help as to the cause of these issues appreciated.

```
using Photon.Pun;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestConect : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    private void Start()
    {
        print("Connecting to server...");
        PhotonNetwork.GameVersion = "0.0.1";
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        print("Connected to server!");
    }

    public override void OnDisconnected(DiconnectionCause cause)
    {
        print("Disconnected from Server for reason " + cause.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First another important note: You should not put any of your custom scripts inside a folder called [`Resources`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeUnderstandingPerformanceInUnity6.html)!

Also afaik `PhotonUnityNetworking` is their official folder of Photon itself. I'ld recommend to not modify or add anything within it, makes it hard to upgrade or fix it later if you have messed it up somehow.

---

**Then to your issue**

It is as the error already suggests

> are you missing a using directive

[`DisconnectCause`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/namespace_photon_1_1_realtime.html#ad61b1461cf60ad9e8d86923d111d5cc9) belongs to another namespace `Photon.Realtime`.

You will need to add a

```
using Photon.Realtime;
```

on the top of that file or have to address it directly like

```
public override void OnDisconnected(Photon.Realtime.DisconnectCause cause)
{
    ...
}
```

Strange though that VisualStudio doesn't note that...

---

The second error is just a follow-up compile error not finding the according method to override because of a supposed signature mismatch since it doesn't know the type you used as parameter due to the error before.

---

**In the future please don't post [screenshots of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and [error messages](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception)! This makes it not only harder to solve the issue but also makes it impossible for others to find this thread when searching for the error message content in order to see if it was already solved somewhere!**

**Rather copy & paste the raw text I your question and format it as code using the `{ }` button.**

Comment: Thank you! I'm currently away from home and I'll try this when i get back home. I appreciate it greatly. I'll update you when I try this out. oh, and as to the links to images. Sorry about that. I wasn't sure on whether to post it as a raw script or as an image, and I wasn't able to post the image without using links as i don't have enough reputation. next time i'll just post the code using { }, thanks!